# Android graphic layout image

Tags: android, image, drawable

Im facing a big problem:

I create a background image drawable-xxhdpi: 1920x1080 and continue with xhdpi 1280x720 and hdpi 960x540. The background image has a square draw to put a button there.

The image of the button in xxhdpi is 360x126, xhdpi 240x84 and hdpi 180x63.

The problem is in hdpi. If i use a device that has resolution 960x540 the image button look good. 
But when i test in a Samsung S2 that has a resolution of 480x800, the background image resizes to fit deppending on the resoluion but the image button not. The image button still be 180x63, and obviously not fit in the draw square of the background image.
I need that the image of the button resize deppending on the resolution of the screen too. I thought android do this automatically.

Activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_image"
tools:context="com.trucouruguayo.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_play"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:onClick="goToPlay" />
```

Please help

Comment: which ide have you use

Comment: I guess not aumatically. It has to depends on the drawables in your differents folders. Could you put your layout and some code ?

Comment: I have my images in the corresponding folders: drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-hdpi

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the background image?
Android is not very good at scaling backgrounds of Views. If you want to align images properly you should use and ImageView, it has a scaleType attribute that allows you to define how to handle different layout sizes and aspect ratios.

Comment: `ImageButton` supports `scaleType` too, if it's only for that reason, no need to change to `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue comes under the different resolution images you do not have in your drawable directory.

If you are using Android Studio. Upload the images using the Android Drawable Image uploader plugin It can handle the similar issue.

here is the link for solution plugin for Android Studio https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=